# Use of global variables within plugin

Tags: plugin-development, variables, wp-localize-script

I am creating my first plugin ever and I found my self having to call the same option variables within various parts of the same page therefore I sought for a solution and stumbled upon global variables which seems to be working for me, however after reading a few articles people seem to be against using global variables and also, I'm not entirely sure if I'm using them the correct way.

Here is what I have;

```
/************************
* Variables
************************/
global $bClass, $cClass, $dClass, $cExpiry;
       $bClass = $cClass = $dClass = $cExpiry =  get_option('myoption');
```

Then since I use a single option to save relevant variables in an array, I would echo the value like this

**jquery**

```
expires: <?php global $cExpiry; echo $cExpiry['cExpiry']; ?>,
```

and then I would also use it in other functions within the same page.

So, it works for me, however I am still wondering whether I am doing it right.

**update**
Thanks for the explanation guys, I ended up using local variables and also found a mistake in my code;

Since I have all my variables saved in a single option, I just used a single local variable;

```
$options = get_option('myoption');
```

Then I would get access to the array by placing the variable inside brackets

```
<?php echo $options['var1']; ?>
```

Whereas before I was doing `$bClass = $cClass = $dClass = $cExpiry =  get_option('myoption');` which is bad.

Comment: This is a PHP question so it would be better on stackoverflow, and yes it's usually bad to do that.

Comment: No reason to close that one. It's not only a PHP question. It's a localize script question as well so it fits into scope. See answer.

Comment: global variables can be used . They are not that bad. Just be little careful. Name them something more unpredictable for ex. $GLOBALS['first_global_unprdictable_name'] = '123'; – beginner 1 min ago   edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're easier ways than this. As @Wyck already stated that using globals is bad idea, here's a short explanation and how to:

### Why globals are bad:

1) Everyone can access them everywhere. First this sounds nice, but you can as well do the following:

```
// Your code: default value
global $foo;
$foo = 'bar';

// User setting:
global $foo;
$foo = get_option( 'baz' );

// Later in your code
if ( 'bar' === $foo )
    // do something important

// Now I, the end user, do this in a template
// or Ernie, the novice developer, does this in his 3rd party plugin:
$GLOBALS['foo'] = 42;
```

and suddenly nothing works like expected. Simple as it is: Globals can get intercepted. They aren't conflict free and no one can ***ever*** be sure what they contain.

2) After you now know that they can change on the fly, you know that they're ***unpredictable***. And if you want to trace them back with your IDE (for e.g. PHPStorm, Eclipse/Aptana, etc.) then you'll never find out where their origin is or where exactly they get changed... unless you sit down for quite a while and use things like Breakpoints and something like XDebug and know your way around.

3) Do I really have to write more? I guess not.

Conclusion: As most options are autoloaded, they're already present on each page/request and don't need to be wrapped in a global. Simply call `get_option()` whenever you need it.

#### How to move Data from PHP to JS

Simple as it is: [`wp_localize_script()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_localize_script/)

Example: (can be used with `login_enqueue_scripts` and `admin_enqueue_scripts` hooks as well)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse115840_scripts' );
function wpse115840_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse_handle', etc... );
    // Here goes the magic:
    wp_localize_script( 'wpse_handle', 'wspeObject', array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'bar' => get_option( 'baz' )
    ) );
}
```

Now you can access all the data from the `wp_localize_script()` array (the 3rd arg) in your javascript file that you just registered/enqueued simply by calling `wpseObject`. The following example would now give you the value `bar`:

```
console.log( wpseObject.foo );
```

and your `wpseObject.bar` would hold your `baz` setting value.

Comment: ...and what if the third party plugin has the same name reference for an add_action process?  not to say that is  highly probable, but if it did, how are the consequences different from having 2 intercepting globals?